# Printing number triangle - squares of two

Tags: java, loops

```
         1
       2 1 2 
     4 2 1 2 4 
   8 4 2 1 2 4 8
```

Trying to print the triangle as above, but I'm having hard time printing squares of two (n *= 2). How do I incorporate this? Currently, it's giving me the following output. Appreciate your help.
Current output (incorrect numbers):

```
         1
       2 1 2 
     3 2 1 2 3 
   4 3 2 1 2 3 4
```

Here is my code so far (for ex, height = 4):

```
     for(int i=1; i<=height; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j <= height-i; j++) 
            System.out.print("   ");

        for(int k=i; k>=2; k--) 
            System.out.printf("%-3d",k);

        for(int l=1; l<=i; l++) 
            System.out.printf("%-3d",l);

    System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Weird, for most people adding/subtracting 1 is easier than multiplication :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go

```
     for(int i=1; i<=height; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= height-i; j++) 
          System.out.print("   ");

        for(int k=1<<i-1; k>=2; k>>=1) 
          System.out.printf("%-3d",k);

        for(int l=1; l<=1<<i-1; l<<=1) 
          System.out.printf("%-3d",l);

        System.out.println();
     }
```

the[<kbd>code</kbd>](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUFJTbE1NbWctLUU).

Comment: Thanks @jiri . It works but I have not learned the bit shift operators (<<) yet, what do they mean when you use it in the for loop?

Comment: `n <<=1` is the same as `n*=2`, but faster. Basically, the number on the right hand side of the `<<` (or `>>`) operator says how many bits are we shifting to the left (multiplying by 2) or to the right (dividing by 2).

As for the for-loop, you can use whatever operation you want on the 3rd position, but the code could be harder to read, because most people expect only `i++`.